# How to configure Firefox not to allow browsing to a specified webdomain?

Tags: firefox, browser

How can I configure Firefox 71 running on Windows 7 Pro to block access to a specified domain, e.g. foo.bar?

Comment: Are you sure you want to prevent a domain for only Firefox? What about other web-browsers? They can still access the domain, then. And Windows comes shipped with other webbrowsers.

Comment: At the moment, yes. It's only to help me resist the temptation to post to a political webforum I no longer want to participate at, not e.g. to protect a child from a harmful site. I have IE and Opera also installed, but FF is the main browser I use and blocking it there will hopefully be enough.

Comment: Anything you can block you can also unblock so it's a pointless exercise

Comment: @DavidPostill - Your premise is correct but it does not support your conclusion. Some of the add-ons with this as their main function have been downloaded by tens of thousands of users, who presumably find them useful in the breaking of unwanted habits.

Comment: @ruffle I doubt whether 10s of thousands of users have managed to break their habits.Are there any statistics backing up your claim that it works? I would be surprised if there were.

Comment: My claim was that it had a point. I would imagine there's a large literature on breaking habits by making it slightly more difficult, but not impossible, to indulge in them. For example some people paint unpleasant-tasting substances on their fingernails to deter them from biting them. It would be easy to say that this was "pointless" because whenever they felt like biting their nails they could find a solvent and scrub the substance off.

Comment: @ruffle: "breaking habits by making it slightly more difficult" - i absolutely understand and i think it's at least worth a try! How much more difficulty it needs to get rid of an unwanted habit depends, but go for it! In case a FF-block is not enough: Get infos about the `hosts`file on your system and block the domain there, that works system-wide. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it out of the box. But there are some Firefox addins for url blocking.
Here is an example of such extension - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blocksite/

Comment: Many thanks. I will have a look at some of the extensions that will do the job. That particular one is unsuitable, though, because it will only work if the user grants the company unpaid permission to keep track of their entire browsing history, including passwords.

Comment: Hmm... All of the Firefox add-ons with this functionality that I've found so far require a grant of permission to "access your data for all websites", including passwords. If there are no suitable add-ons for FF I may have to add a line such as `127.0.0.1 foo.bar` into the hosts file, which will block the site for all browsers but that's not a problem.

Comment: another way is to inplement proxy - https://www.dummies.com/education/internet-basics/filtering-the-web-with-proxy-servers/